# ¿Como saber si una canción en formato MP3 comenzó a reproducirse en C#?

Tags: c#

Lo que me gustaría saber es el como puedo detectar cuando una canción de formato .mp3 comenzó a reproducirse, actualmente se reproduce pero necesito saber en que momento comienza para aplicar una serie de acciones.

Código Actual

```
      public void executen()
        {
            if (myplayer.controls.play==true) {
  //Acciones a realizar
            }


            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(e => activacion(),
                null, 
                TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.01));

        }
```

Me marca error en la condicional del IF y no se a que se deba, tampoco se si lo estoy haciendo correctamente.

Comment: No lo he probado, pero, ¿has intentado hacer un open del fichero .mp3?, si esta en uso entiendo que te daria error.

Comment: Te he puesto una respuesta, aunque no estoy seguro de que control utilizas para reproducir los medios. Deberías editar tu pregunta y especificarlo claramente.

Answer (score 0):

No das mucha información sobre que control estás utilizando, aunque por tu código imagino que usas el Windows Media Player SDK. Si ese es el caso, para saber si se está reproduciendo un tema, lo que debes consultar es la propiedad [playState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564085(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
if (myplayer.playState == 3)
{
    //Se está reproduciendo un medio
}
```

Aunque de esta manera,debes estar consultando el estado continuamente. No lo he probado nunca,pero lo normal sería subscribirse al evento [PlayStateChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564079(v=vs.85).aspx)